# Как синхронизировать проект PhpStorm с FTP

Tags: phpstorm, ftp

Я настроил подключение к FTP-серверу в **Tools > Deployment > Configuration**

Скачал все файлы, но теперь хочу, чтобы при изменении файла у меня в PhpStorm сразу эти изменения загружались на сайт, как настроить эту синхронизацию с FTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Настройка *Upload external changes* — для того, чтобы контролировать **внешние** изменения (сделанные не штормом) и, если надо загружать их. На автозагрузку это никак не влияет.

Для того, чтобы все автоматом синхронизировалось, во-первых надо поставить соединение по-умолчанию (кнопка **Use this server as default** или правой кнопкой мышки на соединении "**Use as default**".

Далее идете в **Tools | Deployment | Automatic upload (always)**

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался - поставил опцию в **File > Settings > Build, Execution > Deployment > options**   `Upload external changes` в положение `allways` и все заработало. Версия IDE 9.0.2